# Initialize form values with redux form initialize function and a GET request

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to initiliaze my form with values coming from my server via an HTTP get request.

My component has a userId has a props (for testing I just hardcoded the id in the request with 1) and I would like to retrieve all the corresponding values from the database and initialize my fields with them.

I use redux form and I found ([here](https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/create-redux-form-validation-initialized-values/)) that it is possible to use the initialize redux form function to get it done. Actually it works when I hardcode the values in my initData object but does not work when retrieving data from the http request as it seems to do the get after creating the initData object..

I don't know if I am clear but in my console it shows me this :

"USER => Object {}"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
Object {ID: 1, FIRSTNAME: "Roger" etc...}
Roger

That means that the get function works, but it is available after the initData object initialization....

Here is an extract of my code :

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  handleInitialize () {
    const user = {};
    // TODO: Gérer le cas où il n'y a pas de userId
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/user/1')// + this.props.userId)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.FIRSTNAME);
        user.FIRSTNAME = data.FIRSTNAME;
        user.LASTNAME = data.LASTNAME;
        user.EMAIL = data.EMAIL;
        user.CITY = data.CITY;
        user.RANKING = data.RANKING;
        user.AVATAR = data.AVATAR;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log('USER => ', user);

    if(user) {
      const initData = {
        'firstname': user.FIRSTNAME.toString(),
        'lastname': user.LASTNAME.toString(),
        'city': user.CITY.toString(),
        'email': user.EMAIL.toString(),
        'ranking': user.RANKING.toString(),
        'avatar': user.AVATAR.toString()
      };
      console.log(initData);
      this.props.initialize(initData);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.handleInitialize();
  }
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry if my question seems obvious, I am a beginner :)

Comment: Because Fetch runs asynchronously. Meaning it won't wait for the get request to finish before running the code below. You'll have better luck if you do the initialization inside of the promise.

Comment: Just as simple as that! Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your `this.props.initialize` inside the `then(data =>{...})` block. If that didn't fix it, make sure you have `enableReinitialize` set to `true`.

```
reduxForm({
  form: 'formName',
  ...
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(LoginForm);
```